# Есть меню которое при скролле появляется. Нужно его изначально скрыть

Tags: javascript, html

Есть меню которое должно появляться при скролле. Он работает, но при загрузки страницы нужно добиться того что бы меню был скрыт, а при скролле появлялся.

Вот код

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if($(this).scrollTop() > 105) {
   $(".scroll-mnu").slideDown();
   return false;
   }
  else {
   $(".scroll-mnu").slideUp();
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стили добавьте:

```
.scroll-mnu {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Оказывается все просто)